# R: How to add values to new columns based on factors in other columns

Tags: r, simulation, dice

I am trying to simulate some dice.

On each side is a food item. My goal is to get all the possible combinations and then summarize them row by row (probably by adding to columns created for the purpose)

I am still not great with R and I have tried lots of things, but I have probably misapplied them so I don't feel safe telling you "I have tried X and it didn't work". Instead I am trying to explain my problem as precisely as I can.

Here is what I am doing:

This adds columns for summarizing the dice rolls. Works fine.

```
Makecolumns <- function(df){
  df[,"Number of fruits eaten"] <- NA
  df[,"Had a vegetable?"] <- NA
  df[,"Exotic fruits included?"] <- NA
  df[,"Number of exotic fruits included?"] <- NA
  return(df)
}
```

This creats the table with all possible combinations. Works fine.

```
createfruittable <- function(nr_one=0,nr_two=0,nr_three=0){
  one <- as.data.frame(c("Bacon","Bacon","Mango","Mango","Pear","Pear","Cucumber","Pear_pear"))
  two <- as.data.frame(c("Bacon","Bacon","Pear","Pear","Pear","Pear","Pear_Mango","Pear_Mango"))
  three <- as.data.frame(c("Pear","Pear","Pear","Pear","Mango","Mango","Cucumber","Cucumber"))

  result <- (expand.grid(c(replicate(nr_one,one),replicate(nr_two,two),replicate(nr_three,three))))
convertfruit(result)

}
```

An example with one of each dice

```
fruits_eaten <- createfruittable(nr_one = 1, nr_two = 1,nr_three = 1)
```

The names of the columns I add should explain what I am trying to summarize/count. If you run the code I think it will be pretty intuitive.

I want to go row by row and count based on the combination of dice results. This is causing me trouble since the results of the dice rolls are factors in my dataframe and I have not been able to use conditions to get the result I need.

Example:
If I in row 1 have Pear, Mango, Cucumber I want to count that this roll had 2 fruits, had an exotic fruit, contained 1 exotic fruit and included vegetables.

Comment: Have you looked at the `combn` function:  (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html) ?

Comment: how do you plan to represent this data in your new column? For example, going with your example above, what would value would indicate "2 fruits, had an exotic fruit, contained 1 exotic fruit and included vegetables"?

Comment: shwan - Will look into it and get back 

ianjd - 2 in "Number of fruits eaten" column, 1 (or "Yes") in "Exotic fruits included", 1 in "Number of exotic fruits included", and 1 (or "Yes") in "Had a vegetable?".

Comment: ianjd - For numbers of fruits I just want to count. For the columns designating the presense or absense of exotic fruit/vegetable I will just dummy code or use a character. 
For the example: 2 in "Number of fruits eaten" column, 1 (or "Yes") in "Exotic fruits included", 1 in "Number of exotic fruits included", and 1 (or "Yes") in "Had a vegetable?

Comment: shwan - I don't think that solves my problem, at least not on its on, as my challenge is how I go about applying the right function to my rows.